# Discord.py add role to user

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I am new to python and creating discord bots in general and I can't for the life of me figure out how to make my bot assign a role to a user upon the users request.

I have scoured the internet for hours on end and have found a few examples but they all produce and error.

Here is the code I have for the command:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("Bots")
async def add_bot(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Bots")
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
in _verify_checks raise CheckFailure('The check functions for command {0.qualified_name} failed.'.format(self))
discord.ext.commands.errors.CheckFailure: The check functions for command add_bot failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `has_role` check.  It doesn't make sense to check if the caller has a role so they can assign themselves that role.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def add_bot(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Bots")
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

Comment: thanks Patrick..i tried that too then i get another error... will make sure what it is tomorrow and post it.

Comment: If i remember correctly it then says i dont have permission altho my bot has all the permissions on Discord but i will make sure.

Comment: Tried what you said, then i get this: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Missing Permissions

Comment: Just figured it out! turns out my bot's role has to be higher in the hierarchy of roles on discord than the role i want to assign. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

For the rewrite version things have changed a little bit, `add_roles` is no more part of `client` but part of the `discord.Member` class therefor the code for the discord.py rewrite version is:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def add_role(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Bots")
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

A minor update for the **REWRITE** version.