# Giving a role to another user with DiscordPy

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to use a command to give a specific role using DiscordPy, but every [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Give+User+role+discordpy) I use brings me to the same answers, that don't help: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49076798/2029983), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55478282/2029983), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451752/how-do-you-assign-roles-with-the-discord-py-rewrite).

Clearly, I'm missing a fundamental part, but i have no idea what. The [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), covers that there is a [add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Member.add_roles) command, but that doesn't give any explanation of how to use it for another user. In fact, trying `await add_roles("Team Captain")` gives the error `NameError: name 'add_roles' is not defined`.

What am I missing here? Why does `add_roles` not exist when it's documented, and how do I use it against a different user.

This is (some of) what I have at the moment, but obviously, doesn't work:

```py
import discord, discord.utils, random, os, re, json
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from dotenv import load_dotenv

client = discord.Client()

load_dotenv()
key = os.getenv('DISCORD_KEY')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))

    #Want these commands in the right channel
    if str(message.channel).lower().startswith("bot"):
        if message.content.lower().startswith("$addcaptain"):
            if len(message.mentions) == 0:
                await message.channel.send("Needs a user to give Team Captain role.")
                return
            else:
                await add_roles("Team Captain") #Doesn't work, and I assume would be against the user who sent the message, not the mentioned one

client.run(key)
key = os.getenv('DISCORD_KEY')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add_roles` is a method that belongs to the `Member` object. This means that you'll need to get the target member, in your case `message.mentions[0]` as `message.mentions` returns a list of Members, and then stick `.add_roles(..)` on the end of it.

Additionally, when adding a role, it accepts `Role` objects, not just a name or ID. This means you'll need to fetch the role first, which can be done in a multitude of ways, but the one I'll use is `utils.get()` (other methods such as `Guild.get_role()` are also available)

This brings us to your code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # code
    if str(message.channel).lower().startswith("bot"):
        if message.content.lower().startswith("$addcaptain"):
            if len(message.mentions) == 0:
                await message.channel.send("Needs a user to give Team Captain role.")
                return
            else:
                role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Team Captain")
                await message.mentions[0].add_roles(role)
```

---

**References:**

- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)
- [`Message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) - `message.mentions[0]` gets the first element of the list, which is the `discord.Member` that was mentioned.
- [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)
- [`Guild.get_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role) - If you want to use this, you'll do:
  `role = message.guild.get_role(112233445566778899)`
  where `112233445566778899` is the `Team Captain`'s role ID.